# DirectShow filter properties window

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, skype

I'm going to write a simple `DirectShow` capture source filter to use with i.e. Skype. I have some parameters I want to expose to the users. Of course I might create a separate exe that sets something into the Windows registry... but I wonder if there is a way to "attach" this property page to the "webcam settings" button always present in applications which uses video inputs.

What does that button actually invokes?

Is there a standard and documented way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every source filter can expose property page(s) to the consuming application. You need to implement the ISpecifyProperyPages interface. For more details and examples you can check this MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375010(v=vs.85).aspx
C++ DirectShow classes also offer you a base class for the actual property page implementation: CBasePropertyPage.